# Names in web config

Tags: wcf

Just suppose I have a wcf service web config file.

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <!-- if you cross domain,here is necessary-->
    <binding name="MyAjaxBind" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior  name="WebApplication2.Service1AspNetAjaxBehavior">
       <!-- here is necessary-->
      <enableWebScript />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors >
    <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
 <!-- here is necessary-->
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"  />
<services>
  <service  name="WcfService1.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
    <endpoint address=""  behaviorConfiguration="WebApplication2.Service1AspNetAjaxBehavior"
      binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyAjaxBind" contract="WcfService1.IService" />
  </service>
</services>
```

For instance:

> ```
>     <binding name="MyAjaxBind"
> ```

"MyAjaxBind" is a random name or having some meaning?
And

> ```
>   <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >
> ```
>
> MyServiceTypeBehaviors is a random name or having some meaning related to the project name?

**EDIT:**
Also I want to know if I have the code for fileless activation inside, then what should be changed?

```
 <serviceActivations>
          <add service="service.wservice"
                relativeAddress="wscccService.svc"
               factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory"
         />
       </serviceActivations>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding name here

```
<binding name="MyAjaxBind" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
```

must match

```
<service ...><endpoint ... bindingConfiguration="MyAjaxBind" ... /> </service>
```

The behavior name

```
<behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >
```

must match

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">....</service>
```

However, what specific name you use is not important.

Comment: If I don't have endpoint section since I use fileless activation, so in this case what about binding name?

Comment: The web.config in your example shows an endpoint.  If this is not what you have in your actual project, please update the question to show your actual code.

Comment: I marked your answer and I wished I get the updated one. Thanks.